# How to Handle Merge Conflicts through Custom Perl Script

Tags: git, perl

I am writing a custom Perl script that should be able to handle merge conflicts in programmatically with minimum interaction from the GIT user when they execute the `git  rebase` command.Currently i was able to detect if GIT goes to `REBASE` state and i execute my list of commands inside a while loop.But the problem is that i can not detect when GIT leaves `REBASE` state.

**Custom Perl Script**

```
while(system("ls `git rev-parse --git-dir` | grep rebase") eq 'rebase-apply/'){
       my $mergeToolMsg=system("git mergetool");
       chomp $mergeToolMsg;
       if($mergeToolMsg != 0){
           //This doesnt hit even
           last;
       }else{
          system("git rebase --continue"); 
       }

    }
```

My requirement is that how can i terminate the loop if there is no merge conflicts or please let me know if there is any other better way to do this.

Comment: chomping the exit status is useless.

Answer (score 1):

[system](http://p3rl.org/system) returns the exit status of the command, not its output. Check `` ` `` or `qx` in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop) for the way to store the output of an external command.

Comment: how can i capture the out put inside while loop and check the condition.i tried following way and not working.`while(`ls \`git rev-parse --git-dir\` | grep rebase || echo no rebase` eq 'rebase-apply'){
        print "in rebase state";
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Finally was able to do it.Please let me know if there is any better way to do this.

```
my $ifRebaseState=`ls \`git rev-parse --git-dir\` | grep rebase || echo no rebase`;
    chomp $ifRebaseState;
    while( $ifRebaseState eq "rebase-apply"){
        $ifRebaseState=`ls \`git rev-parse --git-dir\` | grep rebase || echo no rebase`;
        chomp $ifRebaseState;
        my $ifMergeNeed=`git mergetool`;
        chomp $ifMergeNeed;
        if($ifMergeNeed ne "No files need merging"){
          system("git rebase --continue"); 
        }else{
          last;
        }

    }
```